# Does Azure have any VPN solutions available?

Tags: azure

I have an Azure VM that I want to have clients to be able to access.  I have used OpenVPN in the past, but was wondering if there are any Azure offerings that will allow Windows clients to access that VM.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 3 actually:

1. site-to-site
2. point-to-site
3. express route

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/